# I've installed Aiosqlite, but it won't import

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have `import aiosqlite`, but it says this:
Unable to import 'aiosqlite'

Can someone help? I'm on Visual Studio Code but I can't find out why I can't import Aiosqlite.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried doing `pip install aiosqlite`? If you didn't try doing that and run your code again! The reasoning for this it's because SQLite is a database meaning it needs a couple of packages in order to run it on python! You can read more about it in the links below:

This explains pip:
https://python.doctor/page-pip-installer-librairies-automatiquement

This explains how to install and use databases:
https://pypi.org/project/databases/

If what I said didn't work I suggest you look at this video! It really explains how to use sqlite3! Link: https://youtu.be/Y9DzfPJsP2s

Answer (score 1):

Try with pip3

`pip3 install aiosqlite`

Possible reason -> Async support for Python 3